# Setuppagenumbering adds blank page if started on odd pagenumber

Tags: numbering, page-numbering, context

i'm new in this whole ConText topic and have a question:

I want to generate a pdf. file and this is working fine, so far. I have a title page and a table of content. After this, i would like to start pagenumbering and add a header to all following pages.
Now, it is an "odd" pagenumber (3), where i want to start the numbering. This is adding a blank page for no reason. If the pagenumber is "even", it will not add a blank page and everything would be fine. Do you have any ideas, what could be the issue? Here is the code:

```
\startproduct Test_PDF

\setupheader[state=stop]
\setuppagenumbering[state=stop]
\starttext
{Titel}
\blank[24cm]
\stoptext

\completecontent[criterium=all]

\starttext
\chapter{Revision}
\startalignment[middle]% or center
Some Revisions.
\stopalignment
\stoptext

\setupheader[state=start]
\setupheadertexts[][{Test}]
\setuppagenumbering[location={footer, right}, state=start]

\starttext
\chapter{Abbreviated Terms}
Some Abbreviations.
\stoptext

\stopproduct
```

Many thank in advance.

Best regards
KBH10

Comment: Welcome! There was a very similar question on the ConTeXt mailing list in the last week. Did you see it? Also, can you please edit your question to include a complete minimal example? As it is now, we do not have access to the components. I suggest that you just replace that part with a minimal `\chapter` or whatever makes the example complete (thus, no components at all).

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Unfortunately i didn't see the similar post.  I will have a look on it.

Also, I edited my post, that it is running without the components.

Many thanks, again.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yisqX.png) from your example file. Can you describe from that what you want to change?

Comment: Yes, sure, thank you very much! 
Also in your example I see, that somehow Page 4 was created. And this is not welcome, I don't understand exactly why this page is being created. Do you have any idea?
At the End, there should be Revisions on Site 3 and Abbreviations directly on page 4.

Comment: When i put this
```\setupheader[state=start]
\setupheadertexts[][{Test}]
\setuppagenumbering[location={footer, right}, state=start]```
at the end (after Abbreviations), no extra blank page will be created,

Comment: Any ideas, what could be the reason for it? I'm using this ConText Version: mtx-context | ConTeXt Process Management 1.05 mtx-context | mtx-context | main context file: /../context-win64/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv/context.mkiv mtx-context | current version: 2023.08.27 13:48 mtx-context | main context file: /../context-win64/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkxl/context.mkxl mtx-context | current version: 2023.08.27 13:48 Many thanks in Advance.

Comment: And it seems working fine on Linux, with Version 1.04, instead of 1.05. Any ideas? Is there a possibility to have a look on the changelog? I can't find it online.